# Is there a way to expose 2 graphql endpoints using spring boot starter app graphql-spring-boot-starter?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Currently we are using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${graphql-spring-starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

With this, we are exposing our graphql API using /graphql endpoint. I want to have multiple endpoints like this, /graphql1 and /graphql2 so that I can define different response formats based on the endpoints. what is the best way to do it? Any inputs is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It just boils down to create a `GraphQLHttpServlet` and configure its context path. Under the cover , it uses auto-configuration `GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration` to define a `GraphQLHttpServlet` as a bean, and configure the context path to be `/graphql`.

That means you can reference how `GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration` does and create another `GraphQLHttpServlet` instance that registered to other context path.

The main point is that to register a `Servlet` in spring boot , you can simply create a `ServletRegistrationBean` that wraps the `HttpServlet` which you want to create .See [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-add-a-servlet-filter-or-listener-as-spring-bean) for more details.

A simple example is :

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet> fooGraphQLServlet() {
    //Create and configure the GraphQL Schema.
    GraphQLSchema schema = xxxxxxx;

    GraphQLHttpServlet graphQLHttpServlet = GraphQLHttpServlet.with(schema);
    ServletRegistrationBean<AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
                    graphQLHttpServlet, "/graphql2/*");

    registration.setName("Another GraphQL Endpoint");
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: how about cors setup?