# How can i expose 2 endpoints on spring boot graphql

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I am using following library for spring boot project:

`implementation 'com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2'`

By default it exposes one endopoint on "/graphql", but due to nature of my application i would like to expose 2 endpoints. One on "/internal" and another on "/external". How can i do that?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202051/is-there-a-way-to-expose-2-graphql-endpoints-using-spring-boot-starter-app-graph) for an older version of library that wont work with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can define specific url like this;

```
server.servlet.context-path=/graphql-custom
```

So, if you want to add multiple url;

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>graphql</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/internal</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>graphql</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/external</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```